# Auto refreshing list of items in flutter application retrieved from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, httprequest

I have a flutter application where I retrieve data (temperature readings) from MySQL database. Since I get new data every 30 seconds, I would like my application to auto-refresh the screen so that new data will be displayed automatically each time it is updated. I use `getReadingList()` to retrieve data and use it only in `initState()` method. I know could call `getReadingList()` every 30 seconds, but is there a more efficient built-in solution?

Here's what I have done so far:

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import './models/readings.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late Future<List<Reading>> readings;

  Future<List<Reading>> getReadingList() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('<MY_GET_REQUEST_LINK>')
    );
    final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    List<Reading> readings = items.map<Reading>((json) {
      return Reading.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();
    return readings;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readings = getReadingList(); // readings are retrieved here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Reading>>(
        future: readings,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var data = snapshot.data[index];
              return Text('${data.id}, ${data.temperature}°C, ${data.humidity}%, ${data.reading_time}');
            },
          );
        },
        ),
    ),);
  }
}
```

```
// readings.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Reading {
  final int? id;
  final double? temperature, humidity;
  final String? reading_time;

  Reading({this.id, this.temperature, this.humidity, this.reading_time});

  factory Reading.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    double convertedTemperature = double.parse(json['temperature']);
    double convertedHumidity = double.parse(json['humidity']);
    return Reading(
      id: json['id'],
      temperature: convertedTemperature,
      humidity: convertedHumidity,
      reading_time: json['reading_time'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some arrangements for you. This might be one of the solutions you're looking for. Please can you try?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final StreamController<List<Reading>> readingStreamController = StreamController<List<Reading>>();

  void startStreamReadingList() async {
    Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 30),
      (timer) async {
        if (readingStreamController.isClosed) return timer.cancel();

        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('<MY_GET_REQUEST_LINK>'));
        final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

        List<Reading> readings = items.map<Reading>((json) {
          return Reading.fromJson(json);
        }).toList();

        readingStreamController.sink.add(readings);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startStreamReadingList();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    readingStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Reading>>(
          stream: readingStreamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = snapshot.data![index];
                return Text('${data.id}, ${data.temperature}°C, ${data.humidity}%, ${data.reading_time}');
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Reading {
  final int? id;
  final double? temperature, humidity;
  final String? reading_time;

  Reading({this.id, this.temperature, this.humidity, this.reading_time});

  factory Reading.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final convertedTemperature = double.parse(json['temperature']);
    final convertedHumidity = double.parse(json['humidity']);
    return Reading(
      id: json['id'],
      temperature: convertedTemperature,
      humidity: convertedHumidity,
      reading_time: json['reading_time'],
    );
  }
}
```